# Elasticsearch conditional sorting by different fields

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

Let's say that my buisness need is to sort results differently, based on some "external" parameter that i'm passing to query.

Documents are more or less like:

```json
{
    "transfer_rate": 2000.00,
    "some_collection": [
        { "transfer_rate": 1000.00, "identifier": 1, "campaign": 1 },
        { "transfer_rate": 500.00, "identifier": 2, "campaign": 2 },
        { "transfer_rate": 750.00, "identifier": 3, "campaign": 3 },
        //...
    ]
},
{
    "transfer_rate": 500.00,
    "some_collection": [
        { "transfer_rate": 1000.00, "identifier": 4, "campaign": 1 },
        { "transfer_rate": 2000.00, "identifier": 5, "campaign": 2 },
        { "transfer_rate": 625.00, "identifier": 6, "campaign": 3 },
        { "transfer_rate": 225.00, "identifier": 7, "campaign": 1 },
        //...
    ]
}
```

And now i do have my "parameter", let's say, that's equal to 750.00.

Now, i would like to order this set of documents differently, depends on how different root's `transfer_rate` is compared to given param as follows:

If `doc['transfer_rate'] >= _param` then sort by `doc['transfer_rate']`, else sort by `MIN` of `doc['some_collection'].transfer_rate`.

I know that there could be some document optimisations done, but i wasn't inventing this model, nor i'm allowed to change or re-index.

The tricky part about nested objects is, that they do contain property (in given example it's `campaign`) that **has to match criteria**, so basically:

```
When doc['transfer_rate'] is LT than _param_, order by minimum value of doc['some_collection'].transfer_rate where campaign equals to XYZ
```

So, for given example, with given parameter, documents like first one, should be ordered by `doc['transfer_rate']` and documents like second one, should be ordered by nested.

Thanks for any advices / links / support

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be a pain if you can not reindex the data.

I came up with this query

```json
GET /71095886/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "some_collection",
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "some_collection.campaign": 1
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": {
    "_script": {
      "type": "number",
      "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "source": """
        if (doc['transfer_rate'].value >= params.factor){
          return doc['transfer_rate'].value;
        } else {
          def min = 10000;
          for (item in doc['some_collection']){
            if (item['transfer_rate'] < min){
              min = item['transfer_rate'];
            }
          }
          return min;
        }
        """,
        "params": {
          "factor": 2000
        }
      },
      "order": "asc"
    }
  }
}
```

But it won't work because of the [nested object](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html), and how it is stored in Elastic ([actually Lucene](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html#_limits_on_nested_mappings_and_objects), but let's not get down that road .. yet)

If you add `"nested_path" : "some_collection"` in `_script` you won't have access to the global `transfer_rate` anymore (because stored in a different Lucene documents).

Maybe on thing you can look into is [runtime fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/runtime.html)